# Angular Directive and Controller responding to ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a tutorial on thinkster.io regarding directives responding to ng-click and using its own controller to respond.

Directive & Controller:

```
angular
    .module('unifyWeb')
    .directive('kid', kid);

/* @ngInject */
function kid() {
    return {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: kidCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        link: linkFn,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            done: '&',
        },
        template: "<input type='text' ng-model='chore'>" +
                "{{ chore }}" +
                "<div class='btn btn-success' ng-click='done({chore: chore})'>I\'m done</div>"
    };

    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}

/* @ngInject */
function kidCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    console.log("HELLO");

    vm.logChore = function(chore){
        console.log("HELLO");
        alert(chore + " is done!");
    }
}
   })
```

View:

```
<div class='jumbotron'>
<h1>Test</h1>

 <kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>
</div>
```

What I'm not understanding is that when I click on the custom directive element in the view (kid), it should respond with vm.logChore(). Am I missing something in the link function? I'm not 100% clear how all these pieces interact, which is why I'm doing a tutorial!

My thoughts: I think it has something to do with the scope of the directive and the use of the link function, but I'm not sure.

Also, the controller for the view is separate, do I need to put something in there?

View Controller:

```
angular
    .module('unifyWeb')
    .controller('HomepageCtrl', HomepageCtrl);

/* @ngInject */
function HomepageCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    console.log("HELLO");
    vm.logChore = function(chore){
        console.log("HELLO " + chore);
        alert(chore + " is done!");
    }
}
})
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Trying hard to master directives! Or let me know if I left out vital information, which I could've done.

Thanks in advance! I'll post back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the function as "vm.logchore(chore)" within ng-click. You bound vm to this, which means logchore is not directly on your scope: its on vm.*

Comment: Thanks, that worked! This was what I changed in my directive:

'<div class='btn btn-success' ng-click='vm.logChore({chore: chore})'>I\'m done</div>'

I'm not 100% sure I understand the tutorial because it had me do this in the view: '<kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>', but I got rid of it so now it reads '<kid></kid>' and it works.

But yes, the scope is what I was thinking I was struggling with. THANKS!

Comment: Np! I'd highly recommend John Papa's style guide for angular: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md -- He goes into a lot of detail on $scope, this, and the vm styles.

Comment: thanks! I'll definitely take a look at that. I have an aggressive plan to learn angular so this will definitely help.